# Indian waitlisted train tickets

Tags: online-resources, india, bookings, indian-railways

I am currently sat on a waitlisted Indian train ticket. It is at position  one in the waitlist but with just a day and a half until the train I need to consider alternative transport.

When are waitlisted tickets finally confirmed or denied? Can I check the status remotely or do I have to go to the station?

I am not asking *if* my waitlisted ticket will be confirmed but trying to find out *how and when I will know*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Indian Trains Wait List - will I get a seat?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10322/indian-trains-wait-list-will-i-get-a-seat)

Comment: I don't think that's a duplicate - question is very different, and answers say nothing about whether I can find out sooner than before the charts are drawn up (a couple of hours before depart) nor how/if I can check status other than at the station

Comment: @rg255 If the question is different I suggest you modify it to reflect this.

Comment: The question doesn't ask *if* & there is already further clarifying comments and edits made to the question. It is very clear what the question is about and what the question is not about

Comment: @rg255 while I agree that your question is distinct from the one marked as a duplicate but I think that the *answers* there cover everything you ask including how and when tickets and confirmed and how you can check. What's specifically do you want to know that's not answered there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to know the status of waitlisted tickets by checking their PNR status [here](http://www.indianrail.gov.in/pnr_Enq.html). PNR is a 10 digit identifier for your train ticket.

Train tickets are finalized at the moment of chart preparation, which happens a few hours before the train's departure from the first station. If your ticket is not confirmed till chart preparation, it will be automatically cancelled and your money is refunded.

If your current status is WL 1, I wouldn't worry too much. Train agents who prebook in bulk to resell general cancel just before the train is scheduled to depart and this confirms waitlisted tickets.

Comment: Thanks - is it possible for waitlisted tickets to be confirmed before the charts are prepared (ie if someone cancels a few days before will this be reflected on the ONE checking site?)

Comment: Yes, it is. Waitlisted tickets are confirmed in real time - as confirmed tickets are cancelled.

Answer (score 1):

What Arjun Attam has mentioned is factually very correct and useful, however if you want to really do better than just plain waiting there are applications which sort of use statistical data to predict the confirmation, yes this is like fortune reading and may not be 100% but its better than plain guess or no information at all.

Some of these services are

1. http://www.confirmtkt.com/
2. http://www.trainman.in/

You can use both these and if both indicate the same result, you probably have an answer (but nothing is final and only chart preparation can ultimately answer if you get a confirmation or otherwise).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, I have asked how to find out whether or not the ticket has been changed to confirmed, and when this can happen, not what the likelihood of conversion is

Comment: @rg255 so you downvoted?  I have clearly mentioned that the answer about is factually correct, and only added what I felt could be useful to calm the nerves of someone anxious about confirmation

Comment: @rg255 on second thoughts this also answers your question, these websites also provide a real time update of where you are in addition to providing data on the likelihood of your confirmaiton