# India - Train PQWL likelihood

Tags: trains, india

my friend and I have booked train tickets from Chennai to Chettinad (Rameswaram Express) on 01/11 but could only get on the PQWL, at positions WL2 and WL3. As this is quite an important leg in our journey, I was wondering, on a vague level, whether I should seriously plan other transport options? Basically, from people's experience would you expect our tickets to be confirmed?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TravelSE. Unfortunately questions about predicting Indian Railways ticket confirmation are mostly opinion based and hence off-topic for this site. You can look at the generic question - [India Trains waitlist - will I get a seat](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10322/indian-trains-wait-list-will-i-get-a-seat) or consider resources such as [this](https://indiarailinfo.com/pnr) where users can vote and you can form an opinion on likelihood of a ticket getting confirmed.

Comment: For your journey, PQWL is notoriously slow moving so it may not get confirmed (or even RAC). You can get an RAC ticket right now if you chose to book the train between Chennai and Rameswaram (its final stop). It costs a little more than your current ticket but atleast you are not in pooled quota so chances are high that you may even get confirmed when chart is finally prepared.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Indian Trains Wait List - will I get a seat?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10322/indian-trains-wait-list-will-i-get-a-seat)