# Where can I book the Ooty-Mettupalayam train?

Tags: trains, online-resources, india, bookings

I've read some blogs where people explain that they had to book the Ooty-Mettupalayam toy train (Nilgiri Mountains) a week in advance. I've tried using ClearTrip, but these stations don't appear. Where should I book the tickets for this train? Is possible to do it online?

Comment: AFAIK you can book it on the day. That's what I did.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to book Indian train tickets online?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9562/where-to-book-indian-train-tickets-online)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to book online through [IRCTC](http://www.irctc.co.in)

You will be asked to pick the start point which is MTP and end point is UAM.